# open my app when text is copied from anywhere

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to **open my application and display copied text** whenever i have copied the text from anywhere in android. how can i do this?

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    Button paste;
    TextView display;
    private ClipData clipdata;
    private android.content.ClipboardManager mgr;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        paste = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paste);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        mgr = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

        paste.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                try
                {
                    clipdata = mgr.getPrimaryClip();
                    ClipData.Item item = clipdata.getItemAt(0);

                    String text = item.getText().toString();

                    display.setText(display.getText() + "\n" + text);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Pasted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

- i have tried to open the app using intent
- I'm using android studio
- what are the changes i have need to do

Comment: you need to write service for that which has to be running in background activity will not for that you can read about Service.

Comment: can you show me the code? because i'm beginner in android

Comment: I have added some code you may try that

Comment: @Suyog : did you get a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is a working code which launches your app whenever you copy something anywhere else, it uses a **ClipboardMonitorService** service running in background when the app is first launched:

In **Manifest.xml** put following line under `<application>` tag :

```
<service android:name=".ClipboardMonitorService" />
```

Then in **MainActivity** class start the service in `onCreate()` as following:

```
startService(new Intent(this, ClipboardMonitorService.class));
```

**ClipboardMonitorService** class:

```
package com.kushal.webtest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;



public class ClipboardMonitorService extends Service {

    private ClipboardManager mClipboardManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mClipboardManager =
                (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        mClipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(
                mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);

        System.out.println("Service started running..");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mClipboardManager != null) {
            mClipboardManager.removePrimaryClipChangedListener(
                    mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    private ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mOnPrimaryClipChangedListener =
            new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {

                    String charSequence = mClipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("Copied Link : ====================" + charSequence);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("copiedLink", charSequence);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };



}
```

Comment: but showing Denying clipboard access to com.myapp, application is not in focus neither is a system service for user 0 API 30

Comment: @Ange there might be some different way for API 30

Comment: I have been looking the way to acces the clipboard, and it seams that it's forbidden now for security reason. Only system services can access to the global clipboard, Do you know if it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this register your service in manifest file as you do for activity

```
<service name:".DemoService"/>
```

for starting service your code like startActivity(new Intent(context, YOURACTIVITY.class)) for service startService(new Intent(context, YOURSERVICE.class))

```
 public class DemoService extends Service {
  ClipboardManager clipboardManager;
               private OnPrimaryClipChangedListener clipListener = new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                 public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                    String charSequence = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                    showToast("Copy:\n" + charSequence);

                 }
                };
    }
```

Comment: actually @Suyog you need to study Service class first than only you will understand this code

Comment: @Suyog  have a look at this [Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: its should be `<service android:name=".DemoService"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `addPrimaryClipChangedListener` :

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html

```
ClipboardManager
.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
  @Override
  protected void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
    Log.i("clipboard", "changed text : " + ClipboardManager.getText());
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this,**

```
 ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
 ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(label, text);
 clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

It's worked fine in my app.